# Create backup of excel file

Tags: excel, vba

Currently when i open my xlsm file it changes the name in the title to testing.xlsx and also creates a backup file on the desktop which is not what i am trying to do. All i want is to open the xlsm file, it creates a backup file testing.xlsx then if i make changes to xlsm file, it should update those changes in the testing.xlsx file which should be macro free and the saved changes should remain saved in the xlsm file, currently they are not getting saved.

Also if i close the xlsm file without hitting save it should save itself and the backup without prompting.

Here is the code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\root\Desktop\testing.xlsx",  FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
'ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\root\Desktop\testing.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

I am not a vba expert and haven spent many hours trying to fix this. So asking for some help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I completely get the question, but I think the reason you are creating a .xlsx file is because you are specifying that extension in:

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\root\**Desktop**\testing**.xlsx**",  FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

When the workbook opens, you disable screen updating, compatibility checking and alerting, then save the opened workbook as a .xlsx file on "\root\Desktop", which presumably is your desktop.

Before closing you again disable a load of stuff which I hope you re-enabled at some point (e.g. ScreenUpdating - these are application variables that survive the lifetime of your routine), and then save the workbook to the directory you previously saved it to (e.g. as a .xslx file) Unless you re-save it at some point in between, you will simply be saving the file in the same format as when it was saved by the Workbook_Open event.

Normally, you'd get an alert saying that there were macros in the workbook etc and you might not want to save it as .xlsx, but you `DisableAlert`[ed] the

This is not elegant code, but it should do the job:

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
on error resume next
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="C:\Users\root\Desktop\testingbckup.xlsm"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ThisWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ThisWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = True
End Sub

Sub printActiveWorkbookPath()

Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name

End Sub
```

or the following will normally be fine:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'This simply suprresses the error - it does not try to handle it - achieves the same
'effect as clicking "End" when the error message box pops up
on error resume next
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="C:\Users\root\Desktop\testingbckup.xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: yes i agree to everything..i have done some stuff which i am not sure how it works but got from various internet sources thats why its not working properly. However i am creating the xlsx file which would always be created and will be updated once the xlsm file is updated or opened. Now, i dont know what kind of extension i should give it, but the backup file should obviously be macro free.

Comment: I've extended my answer. As I say, this is not particularly pretty, but it will save a "testing.xlsx" file on load to your desktop, and then a "testing.xlsm" file on close

Comment: everything is working perfect except that now when i open my xlsx file it gives me this excel error "Excel cannot open the file ‘testing.xlsx’ because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file"

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the code again (and actually tested it this time :-p). it should work now.

Comment: hey buddy..sorry to be a pain. But i tested in both 2007 and 2013 but it is giving the same error. Tried both your codes. I think it has something to do with fileformat.

Comment: what is the current file format of the file you are trying to open? If you open a .xlsm Workbook it should work - it is working fine on my computer (Windows 7, Office 365)

Comment: i am trying to open the xlsx file, the one which is getting created by the xlsm file. The xlsm is opening and working just fine.

Comment: That's happening because Excel is confused by the presence of macros in a .xlsx workbook. Is there any reason that the back-up needs to be macro disabled? If you need the back up to be without any macros, you can copy the workbook contents to a new workbook and save it as a .xlsx. Otherwise, the edited code should work

Comment: no there is no particular reason that the backup should be macro disabled. So do we need to save it as xlsm or any other format?

Comment: The simplest thing would be to change the file extension to .xlsm Your backup file will need a slightly different name, or you will overwrite it in the OnClose event. In the edited code, I have used "bckup" to distinguish the backup. Remember that the backup will be overwritten every time the main file is opened - if you need to prevent this (say if someone opens the workbook makes a disastrous change and closes the workbook, then opens and closes it again, you loose you back up) you will need more complicated code

Comment: ok..i get that. Did you try opening the backup file after it is created.? It is giving the debug error code 1004.

Comment: That's because it's firing the back up OnOpen event, and trying to save over the top of itself. You can simply ignore this  - it doesn't effect the integrity of the workbook - it's just a macro bugging out. We can get around this by sticking an "On error resume next" statement in - see code again

Comment: we are very close. Except that the backup file is updated only when we close-open the original file otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: yes, the backup can't update itself. If the backup automatically read data from the original document when ever it was changed, it wouldn't serve as a backup because it would contain any corruptions in the live document. If you want to save to the back up during WorkBook OnClose, then you just need to insert the SaveCopyAs line into the close event. But I'm not sure why you would want to do this